# How to Get all childrens Count in binary tree in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have h that type table

[image]

Now we want full binary tree And full Left and right chides count

Comment: Can you share any code you have so far.  Not everyone is going to provide a free coding service for you.

Comment: I have create a function like function count($parent_id, $leg){$select = "select count(user_id) as total, user_id From users_tbl where parent_id = $parent_id AND leg = $leg"; foreach($select as $key => $value){$count += $value['total']; count($value['user_id'],$leg)}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to keep function in loop then run it , hope this helps you.

Thanks

Comment: I will not recommend this method. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868711/get-all-children-by-parent-id-and-where-clause-in-mysql so that the recursion is done in MYSQL itself which also optimizes the performance rather doing on client end.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not efficiently possible using only SQL (the fact that each node can only have two children, left and right, does not help because the nodes can still be nested arbitrarily deep), you have to do it recursively using PHP:

```
function countChildren($parentId) {
    $children = (`SELECT user_id FROM table where parent_id = ?`, $parentId); // Pseudocode, use a prepared statement with your ORM or MySQL library/PDO
    $count = count($children);
    foreach($children as $userId) {
        $count += countChildren($userId);
    }
    return $count;
}
```

However, if you switch your table to use a [nested set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) instead of a tree, querying children for information becomes much more efficient:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table AS t JOIN table as parent_table ON (t.left > parent_table.left AND t.right < parent_table.right) WHERE parent_table.user_id = ?;
```

Comment: NO THIS NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  leg , count(user_id)as Count FROM table GROUP BY leg
```

This will show the count of left and right

Comment: if you wnt children count by its parent id just group by its parent_id, I cant Understand What is your requirement.

Comment: actually all children count not only parent i want parent - parent - parent  count